# Knockout : getting the value parameter in ko.utils.objectForEach(object, function (key, value) does not give me the exact value of the key

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to iterate through an Object in KO, i get correct the key but when I log the value parameter I get a function like this: `function c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.Ua(c[F],arguments[0])&&(c.ia(),c[F]=arguments[0],c.ha()),this;a.l.sc(c);return c[F]}`

How do i get the real value instead of a function

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the observable it self... observables are just plain old javascript functions.
Do not log the "value", log the "value()".
Post some code so we can better find the issue there